# ASP.NET Razor: add to Model moved List box items from another list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 list boxes like below:

```
@Html.ListBox("SelectedList",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectedList, new { @class="listbox" , id="list2" })
<input id="btnAdd" type="Button" class="submit"  value="Add"/>
<input id="btnRemove" type="Button" class="submit" value="Remove"/>
@Html.ListBox("NonSelectedList",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.NonSelectedList,new { @class="listbox" , id="list2" })
```

I move the items between lists using add and remove buttons.
Everything working fine but I want to add the selected Items to my Model object.
Is there a way i can do that?

Comment: may be you can have a hidden field and append selected items to it.

Comment: how can i update hidden field in JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: you can have a global array and a function to append element to an array call this function when you are adding and append data to hidden field. complete documentation of an array is here http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/